# Can't compile the project android vison

Tags: android, android-vision

I have problem with project android vision. When run this project and finish compile show message gradle bulid

```
Error:Failed to crunch file C:\Users\MagdaD\Desktop\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png into C:\Users\MagdaD\Desktop\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
```

and next

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\MagdaD\Desktop\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png into C:\Users\MagdaD\Desktop\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
```

I try replace this image but can't help

Comment: edit image name `abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png` .Remove `DIGIT`

Comment: `abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.png`